# How do I add the matching records of one of two different datasets with the same date to the other in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 different datasets.

Table-1: df1

```
Date          sales   product 
2021-08-01    10000   a
2021-08-02    575     a
2021-08-03    12212   a
2021-08-04    902     a
2021-08-05    456     a
```

Table-2: df2

```
Date          sales   product 
2021-08-03    1000    b
2021-08-04    435     b
2021-08-05    759     b
2021-08-06    9123    b
2021-08-07    642     b
```

In python, I want to create a new data set which is all records of df2 that match df1 with date columns are added to df1 and I want to assign the value 0 for non-match dates.

New Dataset:

```
Date          sales_a   sales_b  
2021-08-01    10000     0
2021-08-02    575       0
2021-08-03    12212     1000
2021-08-04    902       435
2021-08-05    456       759
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Check out `pd.merge()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on the date and sales columns, joining on Date on the left dataframe (df1), adding the suffixes _a and _b to the resulting column names. You can then fill in any nans with 0 to get the desired output:

```
  df1[['Date', 'sales']].merge(df2[['Date', 'sales']], on='Date', how='left',
                               suffixes=['_a', '_b']).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
         Date  sales_a  sales_b
0  2021-08-01    10000      0.0
1  2021-08-02      575      0.0
2  2021-08-03    12212   1000.0
3  2021-08-04      902    435.0
4  2021-08-05      456    759.0
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer. Your answer solved my problem in the first place. But when I apply the same code with different dataframe to the created df3, the rows duplicate. I tried to delete duplicate rows with .drop_duplicate(), but it doesn't work. @emiob

Comment: @Rachel if this answered your original question, then it would be good if you can accept it. As for duplicating on a different dataframe, I can't help without seeing df3 and the code you're using. Maybe update your question if what you're asking is different to what you've posted?

Comment: Or ask a new question if it's a different problem